# Wemo and Python Incorporation For a beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x, home-automation

let me give a little back story before i ask the question
*this is my first post to StackOverflow. so im sorry if i offend anyone or if i dont know the proper rules attached to this forum

*im a beginner in coding and dont understand much of the complex codes, so if you have code in your answer please explain it so i can better myself , thanks in advance

- the actual prgm im working on is for my mother who isnt so tech-intelligent so i decided to attempt to make a prgm called "APEDS" (Automated Personal Error Detection System)

http://pastebin.com/zt1zaVH9

the part of the code i have a question with is

```
    # [ 1 ] option ( internet ) 
elif action == '1':
    def submenu1():
        print(
"""
What Problems are u having with the internet?
"""
"""
[1] - Internet is Slow / Not Working 
[2] - There's no Wi-Fi / Can't connect to Wi-Fi44
[3] - 
[4] - Forgot my Wifi Password !
""")
    action = input("Please Select a Number: ")

    if action == '1':
        print('1')
    elif action == '2':
        print('2')
    elif action == '3':
        print('3')
    elif action == '4':
        print('4')
    else:
        print('\nNo valid choice has been selected please try again')
        time.sleep(3.5)
```

under the first option i would like it to ping a couple different reliable sources and lets say 5 in total , and if more then 4 fail it will proceed to the next step which is activate the reset cmd to the WeMo (which is attached to the router/modem) ( since the wifi will be off the cmd needs to be something like off> wait 30 sec> on )

the main part is i have no idea how to incorporate the WeMo api (https://github.com/iancmcc/ouimeaux/tree/master)

if i need to install anything on my computer to get it working please explain in detail how to do it

thanks again and im sorry if this was hard to follow

-BOF007

Answer (score 0):

For install that API you can use PIP

```
sudo pip install ouimeaux
```

If you don't have PIP you can install it with your package manager. In Archlinux for example

```
sudo pacman -S python-pip
```

I don't know that API but you can install it and then reading [docs](http://ouimeaux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and try code examples so you will understand it. Your goal don't seems so hard, good luck!

Comment: is it bad that im not on Linux ? and what do you mean try code examples ?

Comment: I feel so better using GNU/Linux for developing (and for all purposes), but in Windows you can use PIP too. It's installed by default in Windows Python bundle and you can use it opening a cmd as an admin. `pip install ouimeaux` should work.

Comment: where would i type in this `pip install ouimeaux`into ? and is it py 2.7 or 3.4 ?

Comment: I don't know if the API is for Python2 or Python3. You only should open a command prompt as an admin like [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/command-prompt-windows-8.htm) and type that.